PyCharm и OpenCV
Помогите пожалуйста, не знаю что делать. На Windows VPS стоит PyCharm, и я поставил OpenCV, но что бы я не пробовал сделать, всегда выдаёт ошибку. Вообще мне это нужно, чтобы бот автоматически нашёл и нажал кнопку на плагине браузера, через RDP соединение с этим справляется
pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Target2.png')

но мне нужно через VNC, и там не работает. Или OpenCV тоже не будет работать через VNC?
Ставил с помощью команды:
pip install opencv-python

При установке выдал
C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\TestCV2>pip install opencv-python 
Collecting opencv-python Using cached opencv_python-4.10.0.84-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (20 kB) 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in c:\users\administrator\pycharmproj ects\testcv2\venv\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.23.5) 
Using cached opencv_python-4.10.0.84-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (38.8 MB) 
Installing collected packages: opencv-python 
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.10.0.84 – 

Версия Python 3.11.4
Сама ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\TestCV2\main.py", line 2, in <module> 
 import cv2 
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\TestCV2\venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module> 
 bootstrap() 
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\TestCV2\venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap 
 native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2") 
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module 
 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: Не найден указанный модуль.


Неужели никто не знает?

Ну там же написано - не может найти модуль cv2. Вы его ставили? Если да, то в какое окружение? Выбирайте то же окружение для запуска скрипта, в которое вы поставили этот модуль. У питона на одном компьютере может быть много разных окружений - с разной версией питона и с разным набором библиотек.

Так я его ставлю через терминал PyCharm, пишет что установилось, а потом всё равно  эта ошибка

Почитайте про окружения питона. И тут были уже подобные вопросы, поищите. В PyCharm нужно выбрать окружение где-то там в интерфейсе. Не факт, что в терминале у вас из того же окружения запуск.

Но другие библиотеки работают

Их тоже вы таким же образом ставили?

Добавьте в вопрос вашу версию питона и каком образом вы ставили cv2, какой конкретно командой. Может ещё в версиях дело что и куда вы ставили. И что при установке cv2 было выведено в консоль - тоже приведите в вопросе. Может там ошибка была.

Ставил с помощью команды pip install opencv-python

При установке выдал C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\TestCV2>pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
Using cached opencv_python-4.10.0.84-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in c:\users\administrator\pycharmproj
ects\testcv2\venv\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.23.5)
Using cached opencv_python-4.10.0.84-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (38.8 MB)
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.10.0.84

Версия Python 3.11.4

Добавьте всё это в вопрос. В комментариях сложно читать.

Сделал, обновил

Неужели никто не знает? Пробовал и с командной строки Windows VPS установить, и в терминале PyCharm, но всегда одна и та же ошибка((((((

Такая проблема была.
Пофиксил установкой Media Feature Pack (использую Windows 10 N)

Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он станет недоступным или навсегда закрытым

Спасибо огромное, очень помогли. Теперь всё получилось
